# Has Kuwait banned several Muslim-majority countries from entry?

Tags: government

From [Kuwait issues its own Trump-esque visa ban for five Muslim-majority countries](http://www.albawaba.com/editorchoice/kuwait-issues-its-own-trump-esque-visa-ban-five-muslim-majority-countries-932174)

> Citizens from five Muslim-majority countries will no longer be able to obtain Kuwaiti visas, after reports the Gulf state issued tight entry restrictions that mirrored US President Donald Trump's Muslim ban.
>
> Syrians, Iraqis, Iranians, Pakistanis and Afghans will not be able to obtain visit, tourism or trade Kuwaiti visas with the news coming one day after the US slapped its own restrictions on seven Muslim-majority countries.
>
> Passport holders from the countries will no lot be allowed to enter the Gulf state while the blanket ban is in place and have been told not to apply to visas.

Meanwhile, one of the articles linked to even says the ban was in place from [2011](https://www.alaraby.co.uk/english/news/2017/2/1/kuwait-issues-trump-like-visa-bans-for-five-muslim-majority-countries)

Does Kuwait have, or has it had, a ban on several Muslim-majority countries?

A ban on Jewish-majority Israel, though very plausible, would not be confirmation of this claim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not true according to Kuwait's ambassador to Pakistan. [Here is an article by Pakistan Today](http://www.pakistantoday.com.pk/2017/02/02/no-visa-ban-on-pakistanis-by-kuwait-ambassador/), from the article:

> Pakistan’s ambassador in Kuwait on Wednesday said that Kuwait hasn’t
>   placed a visa ban on Pakistani nationals.
>
> Ghulam Dastagir said that news on social media about the ban are
>   baseless, further adding that same news had sprung up in 2011.
>
> Earlier, a newspaper claimed that Kuwait has banned nationals from
>   Syria, Iraq, Iran, Pakistan and Afghanistan. It claimed that the ban
>   included on tourism, visit and trade visas as well as visas sponsored
>   by spouses.